# Set Content-Security-Policy response header on VSCode Server web UI

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-server

I am using the [vscode server](https://coder.com/) behind a reverse proxy inside the jupyerlab extension proxy and I would like to modify the Content-Security-Policy response header. Specifically I would like to modify the frame ancestor to the domain URL which is used to connect. Otherwise I get a `"Refused to load https://xxxx because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy"`. If I enforce it on the reverse proxy it works, but I would rather want it enforced from the sender of the response. Anyone knows how to solve this?